# How to access useEffect's async data in another function within a component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a functional component with Hooks:

```
const Filters = () => {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  const getOption = type => options.find(el => el.name === type);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('someURL')
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(result => setOptions(result.data), error => console.log(error));
    // trying to check options array now
    console.log(getOption('type')); // returns undefined
  }, []);
}
```

The purpose of this approach is to fetch a data, then run this data through a computed function, to get a single object based on `getOption(type)`. If i use `useEffect(() => fetch(), [options]);` then i'll get endless loop with `console.log()` outputs.

So, `setOptions(result.data)` is async i guess, just like `setState` in a class component, but doesn't accept a second parameter to use when async request is done.

I want to modify my `options` array after a `fetch()` is done with my `getOption()` function.

Comment: A solution could be to circumvent the problem and write a system that "takes" synchronous request to "do" something asynchronous, and has query system to check the state of the asynchronous function. Basically a high level interface around promises.... But I hope there's a better solution than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another `useEffect` to execute a function when `options` is modified:

```
const Filters = () => {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  const getOption = type => options.find(el => el.name === type);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('someURL')
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(result => setOptions(result.data), error => console.log(error));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!options) {
      return;
    }

    console.log(getOption('type'));
  }, [options])
}
```

Comment: This works, but i have a question, why do i have 2 console outputs? First one is `undefined` and a 2nd one is with an actual data, as expected. But why the first one even fires with undefined data? Seems like i understand this, it fires `undefined` because on the mounted stage, my `options` array is empty, then when options are filled from API - i get a correct data output in a console. But is there a more elegant way to this?

Comment: As mentioned in React Documentation: `The function passed to useEffect will run after the render is committed to the screen.` meaning that the first time your component renders (fetch has not ended yet), the `console.log` will be executed, thus the `undefined`. See: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

Comment: Yeah, i just figured out it now, but is there a better approach for this? Is it perfectly fine to use multiple `useEffect()` in a single component?

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can check if `options` is defined before executing the function.

Comment: A check `if (!options) return;` doesn't prevent from `undefined` console output on the component mount stage.

Comment: You're right sorry, try `if (options.length === 0) return;`